# Holy holy=Holy s###?

Tags: idioms, vocabulary, slang

I thought I heard the store manager (a native English speaker, mid-20's) muttered to himself like "Holy holy." That was when the store was newly opened and was so crowded with lots of customers. He was tremendously busy that day and seemed irritated with the register bug. Did the saying mean "Holy s####"? Is the phrase often used among youngsters in US?

Comment: [Holy moley!](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Holy+moley!) (exclamation used by the comic book character Captain Marvel).

Comment: ... A minced oath, an attempt to convince oneself and/or others that what one is saying is not really bad. I once heard 'Hallelujah' being used essentially as a swear-word.

Comment: It's a [substitute swear word](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Substitute+swear+word)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: No one says "holy holy" instead of "holy s#!t," except insofar as people say all sorts of random things, especially when they're mad. It is not a standard English thing. However, the formulation "Holy ___, Batman" is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_exclamations_by_Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Holy holy is a substitute swear
>   OR
>
> > you could possibly have misheard him say holy moley - this features in comic books, I believe